# Is my trigger executing?

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I created my very first MSSQL trigger in MSSQL SERVER 2008 following the following guide; https://web.archive.org/web/20210306173842/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/tips/t051706-1.shtml

I have setup mail in the SQL Server Management Studio and test mails run successfully, but I never get the email from my trigger. Two questions;

1) Is my trigger valid?
2) Where does MSSQL Server log when a trigger is executed?

```
CREATE TRIGGER updTicketHeader
on TicketHeader
FOR UPDATE
AS
IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM inserted) = 1
BEGIN
declare @body varchar(3000)
declare @TicketNumber int
declare @originatorFirst varchar(64)
declare @originatorLast varchar(64)
declare @originatorEmail varchar(64)
declare @ticketSubject varchar(16)
declare @priority int
declare @ticketDescription varchar(128)
SELECT @TicketNumber = ticketNumber,
@originatorFirst = originatorFirst,
@originatorLast = originatorLast,
@originatorEmail = originatorEMail,
@ticketSubject = ticketSubject,
@priority = priority,
@ticketDescription = ticketDescription
FROM inserted

SET @body = 
'New ticket ' + @TicketNumber + ' has been created!
First Name: ' + @originatorFirst + '
Last Name: ' + @originatorLast + '
Email: ' + @originatorEmail + '
Priority: ' + @priority + '
Ticket Subject: ' + @ticketSubject + '
Ticket Description: ' + @ticketDescription

EXEC master..xp_sendmail
@recipients = 'support@atbashservices.com',
@subject = 'New Ticket ' + @ticketNumber + ' has been created!',
@message = @body
END 
GO
```

Thanks to Code Magician for the help!

My trigger is now working with the following code;

```
CREATE TRIGGER updTicketHeader
on TicketHeader
FOR INSERT
AS
IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM inserted) = 1
BEGIN
declare @body varchar(3000)
declare @TicketNumber varchar(8)
declare @originatorFirst varchar(64)
declare @originatorLast varchar(64)
declare @originatorEmail varchar(64)
declare @ticketSubject varchar(16)
declare @priority varchar(8)
declare @ticketDescription varchar(128)
SELECT @TicketNumber = ticketNumber,
@originatorFirst = originatorFirst,
@originatorLast = originatorLast,
@originatorEmail = originatorEMail,
@ticketSubject = ticketSubject,
@priority = priority,
@ticketDescription = ticketDescription
FROM inserted

SET @body = 
'New ticket ' + @TicketNumber + ' has been created!
First Name: ' + @originatorFirst + '
Last Name: ' + @originatorLast + '
Email: ' + @originatorEmail + '
Priority: ' + @priority + '
Ticket Subject: ' + @ticketSubject + '
Ticket Description: ' + @ticketDescription

EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
@recipients = 'support@atbashservices.com',
@profile_name = 'Default',
@subject = 'New Ticket has been created!',
@body = @body
END 
GO
```

Comment: As Code Magician pointed out, in order for this trigger to work, I needed to change the 'FOR UPDATE' to 'FOR INSERT' the trigger started executing after that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Woah. Why is your trigger `FOR UPDATE` Yet your email body is talking about a new ticket being created?** Consider using `FOR INSERT`

*Just in case that's not the only issue, everything below is still worth a read.*

First it's entirely possible that your trigger is firing but not doing anything. *never assume* your update/insert/delete is only one record.

I see your code is checking for a single row affected but if there are two rows updated at the same time, nothing will happen. It would probably be better to code a loop if you want email to be send for every update.

SQL doesn't log that a trigger is firing, Triggers are as transactional as the SQL that triggers them. In other words, if your update worked, your trigger worked. In this case, either you are doing a multi-row update that your trigger is skipping or you've not configured `xp_sendmail` correctly. I suspect the latter.

I would recommend against using `xp_sendmail`. For starters, it's deprecated now. It's also a hassle to configure, it requires installing a MAPI client (like outlook) on your database server.

The preferred way to send email from the database these days is using `sp_dbmail`. Rather than SQL server sending commands to a local install of outlook express, `sp_dbmail` will simply use SMTP.

Also, sp_dbmail *will log* your emails that are sent. It keeps copies of outgoing e-mail messages and stores them in the following tables: 
`sysmail_allitems`, `sysmail_sentitems`, `sysmail_unsentitems`, `sysmail_faileditems`.

It becomes much easier to troubleshoot your actual issue. Using `sp_dbmail` Sent item statuscan be seen in sysmail_mailitems table. if `sent_status` is 1 then it sent successfully, failures are 2 and 3 is unsent.

Anyway, read all about dbmail [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175887%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

And [here's a video](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/dd939167.aspx) describing how to configure DB mail in SQL 2008

Comment: Awesome, that is alot to take in, but that is definetley the right diretion! Thanks.

Comment: Happy to help @CryptoJones. I suspect that simply changing your trigger to `FOR INSERT` will get things working assuming xp_sendmail is set up correctly. Otherwise, the video will help you get dbmail set up and tweak your trigger to use it and you'll be good to go. FWIW that 4guysfromrolla article is over a decade old!

Comment: The FOR INSERT worked perfectly. It then complained about xp_mail not being enabled on the service profile meaning that was the actual problem with my trigger! I am reading up on DB mail now to make the other change!

Thanks Again!